# Как добавить захват select и textarea в ajax отправке письма?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть Ajax скрипт отправки формы обратной связи.

```
$(function() {
        $('#writeAppointment').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var data = new FormData();
            form.find(':input[name]').not('[type="file"]').each(function() {
                var field = $(this);
                data.append(field.attr('name'), field.val());
            });
            var filesField = form.find('input[type="file"]');
            var fileName = filesField.attr('name');
            var file = filesField.prop('files')[0];
            data.append(fileName, file) ;

            var url = 'multisend.php';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

но он читает только input.
Как добавить в него еще select и textarea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как добавить в него еще select и textarea ?

Полагаю, `select` и `textarea` находятся внутри тэга `form`?

Дать им атрибуты `name` с непустыми значениями.

```
var data = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  ...
```

Передайте элемент формы в конструктор `FormData`, и в переменной `data` окажутся все данные из именованных элементов формы с пользовательским вводом.

@ВладимирКлыков - спасибо, приятно, когда тебя понимают ).

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(this);
  for (var pair of data.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="n1" value="test"/>
  <select name="n2">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="n3">My Text</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Mesuti Осталось убедить в этом мою жену. Покажу ей сегодня Ваш комментарий ).

Comment: Меня просто смутил конкретный поиск по input'ам Почему именно они не подтягиваются если у них уже есть name?

Comment: @Mesuti У Вас же вызывался конструктор без параметров `new FormData();`, то есть изначально `data` был пустой.